# How do I stop my player or camera from jittering during player movement?

Tags: unity, camera, movement, rigidbody, third-person-view

In my game, I have a third person character. The player moves with a rigidbody and has `isKinematic` set off with interpolate on. In the script, it moves with `Rigidbody.MovePosition` with the y position froze. Here's my player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed;

   public Rigidbody rb;

   public Transform camPos;

   // Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       camPos = Camera.main.transform;
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       if (Input.GetKey("w"))
       {
           rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (camPos.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
       }                                          
       if (Input.GetKey("s"))
       {
           rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (-camPos.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
       }
       if (Input.GetKey("d"))
       {
           rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (camPos.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
       }
       if (Input.GetKey("a"))
       {
           rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (-camPos.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
       }

       rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
   }
}
```

For my camera, I have it lookat the player and lag behind smoothly. Here's that script:

```
//Hakeem Thomas
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamPos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothTime = 0.5F;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    public GameObject player;

    private float mouseX, mouseY;
    public int mouseX_Speed, mouseY_Speed;
    
    //mouseSensitivity
    public int turnSpeed;

    void getMouseXY()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * smoothTime;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * smoothTime;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        getMouseXY();
        // Define a target position above and behind the target transform
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 1.5f, -2.5f));

        // Smoothly move the camera towards that target position
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
        transform.LookAt(target);

        target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((mouseY * mouseY_Speed), (mouseX * mouseX_Speed), 0);
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, (mouseX * turnSpeed), 0);

    }
}
```

My issue is that whenever the player moves either the camera/player jitters.

I have debugged the player transform y position to make sure it wasn't moving up or down (it doesn't). To help with this issue I have either turned down the `Fixed Timestep` under Time in the project settings or put the code in the camera script is fixed update instead of late update (which is an issue based on my research).

I know `MovePosition` for the player isn't the right way to move, but I don't know how to make the player move in the direction the camera is facing with `rb.velocity`. I suspect the issue may lay in the player script with variable `camPos`. Either way, I would like to stop the jittering.

Answer (score 1):

I made this mistake too:

```
target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((mouseY * mouseY_Speed), (mouseX * mouseX_Speed), 0);
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, (mouseX * turnSpeed), 0);
```

When you write to any part of the transform - including rotation - you disable rigidbody interpolation for that frame. The physics engine is bypassed, so it treats it as though the object has teleported, and tries to resume physics-driven, interpolated movement next frame.

If your object has a rigidbody, ensure you're routing *all* changes to its transformation, both position and rotation, through that body. That way the physics engine remains in control and you get the full benefit of its interpolation.

You're already using `MovePosition()` instead of `transform.position = ...`, so you should use `MoveRotation()` instead of `transform.rotation = ...`.

Comment: Thanks, not just for the answer but the explanation was invaluable. So, I basically should just replace most of my manual code with standard unity library stuff?

Comment: Just replacing `transform.rotation =` with `MoveRotation` should suffice for fixing this problem.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that my camera doesn't move with a rigidbody. The camera script is attached to the camera. How would I use MoveRotation?

Comment: To quote the answer above: "**If your object has a rigidbody**, ensure you're routing all changes to its transformation, both position and rotation, through that body."  - If your object does *not* have a rigidbody, this advice does not apply, and it is OK to write to the transform directly, with `transform.rotation =`, `transform.Rotate()` etc.

Comment: @DMGregory I think the problem here is he's moving the target in `FixedUpdate()` but updating the camera in `Update()`. In my experience this causes jitter because the two updates are not in sync.

Comment: That's OK if you're using interpolation, as OP is here. Moving the camera in Update or LateUpdate, and manipulating physics in FixedUpdate is exactly the normal pattern for this kind of behaviour, and can produce beautifully smooth gameplay when done right. There are just a few gotchas to avoid to make sure interpolation does what you need.

Comment: @DMGregory I just tested it using his camera code, and I get jitter when moving the camera in Update/LateUpdate, but no jitter when moving the camera in FixedUpdate

Comment: That is one solution for judder on the character, but it's one that would often be undesirable, since it means your camera movement is less smooth. Every so often you'll show two frames in a row with the camera in the same position, because no FixedUpdate occurred in-between to move it. Using rigidbody interpolation effectively can avoid this issue.

Comment: So another way to make this work is make the camera have a rigidbody and interpolate? @DMGregory

Answer (score 0):

Another common cause of jitter is combining movement code in `Update()` with movement code in `FixedUpdate()`.

The default physics step is 0.02 seconds, which is 50 updates per second. That's slightly less than the typical monitor refresh rate of 60fps. This means every tenth of a second, you can expect an update sequence that looks sort of like this:

```
FixedUpdate
Update
FixedUpdate
Update
FixedUpdate
Update
FixedUpdate
Update
Update   <--------
FixedUpdate
Update
```

Because we have 5 physics updates for every 6 screen updates, about 10 times a second we're going to have a frame where the camera moves but the target didn't move. This causes very noticeable jitter.

There are two easy solutions, each which has its own downsides:

1. Reduce the physics update timestep (increase the number of physics updates per second). This increases the performance cost of running physics, and may not help on devices where the monitor refresh rate is much higher (e.g. on a 120hz or 240hz monitor).
2. Move the camera during FixedUpdate. Users with high-refresh-rate monitors may be able to tell that the camera motion isn't as smooth as it should be (since the camera is moving at 50hz but rendering at 120/240hz), but at least it shouldn't jitter.

I just made a simple test project to reproduce your issue. I saw major jitter when moving the camera in `Update()/LateUpdate()`, and no jitter when moving the camera in `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: Putting the code in Fixedupdate would solve my problems but I don't want more issues down the road. It seems like a lose-lose situation.